# How do I efficiently wait for a hardware interrupt?

Tags: c++, multithreading

How can I suspend or otherwise block a thread and then resume it when a particular condition occurs?

In other words.. I have a keyboard that communicates to a microcontroller. When a key gets pressed, the controller throws a hardware interrupt on a pin (you'll understand when you'll see the code), which corresponds to a boolean value.

```
bool condition = this->MCP23017->readPin(this->INTERRUPT_KB) == this->MCP23017->PIN_LOW
```

I need something that suspends the thread (yes, that condition is inside a method who is called by a std::thread object) while the condition is still false, and reactivates it when it is true.

If I put a loop around the variable, the CPU goes at 100%, and this wastes a lot of power because the thread stays in active-waiting state. I need something more efficient than that.

Comment: mmmm, is not that a condition variable?

Comment: Yes, but if I put a loop around the variable the CPU goes at least on 100% of use, and this wastes a lot of power because the thread stays in active-waiting state, in fact, I asked for suspending a thread

Comment: How quick does the response need to be? If you polled with a Sleep(), then the cpu overhead would be reduced. In the case of Windows, you can set the timer resolution for Sleep() down to about 1 millisecond. Can the condition trigger an interrupt that could then trigger a mutex or semaphore to resume a thread pending on the mutex or semaphore?

Comment: The response needs to be at least around 250 and 500ms. I'm on raspbian (raspberryPi) I've read a lot of threads that suggest to not implement the sleep function because it doesn't let the scheduler to put your thread in suspend-mode (it stays in active-waiting state), and I'm trying to reduce this "wasting resources" due to a lot of threads with loops that iterates on these conditions. I've tried implementing a condition_variable wait_until with that condition, but it is not accepted because it needs a predicate, not a simply bool param

Comment: I have little knowledge about the threading bits, but wouldn't `[]()->bool{return this->MCP23017->readPin(this->INTERRUPT_KB) == this->MCP23017->PIN_LOW;}` be the predicate?

Comment: @rcgldr has it right-ish. In the handler-thread, wait on a semaphore.  In the interrupt-handler, post a unit to the semaphore and exit via. the OS interrupt-handler entry point, requesting an 'immediate' reschedule upon return from interrupt-state.  Polling/sleep loops are just lame and defeat the primary purpose of multithreaded RTOS - high-performance I/O.

Comment: Read the docs for your platform, specifically how the driver documentation says you should wait for a hardware interrupt.

Comment: There is no support for my kernel, someone suggest to write a new kernel on my own but it's impossible.

It's a raspberry Pi, and this interrupt occurs into a device which is connected through I2C. There's no way of doing it by hardware, I need a software interrupt to avoid polling

Answer (score 1):

Use [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) to make use of **wait/notify** to suspend a thread indefinitely until a condition is satisfied and the thread is notified.

```
std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cond;
std::atomic_bool condition_flag{false}; // Used as condition in this example.

// Create a new thread of execution.
std::thread t{[&] {
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{m}; // Aquire lock on mutex.

        /* Wait until notified. Lock is released while waiting.
           When notified; first check if condition is satisfied.
           If not then resume waiting. */
        cond.wait(lock, [&] { return condition_flag.load(); });
    } // Release lock on mutex.

    /* Resume thread execution. */
}};

/* Do something else in original thread before notifying. */

condition_flag = true; // Atomically satisfy condition.
cond.notify_all();     // Notify all threads waiting on 'cond' to reevaluate condition.

t.join(); // Wait for thread to finish execution.
```

Comment: You can't `notify` a `condition_variable` inside an interrupt handler. Such routines are thread-safe, not reentrant. (Although, it's possible that this is supported on his platform.)